# Shiny - submitButton and conditionalPanel

Tags: r, shiny

I have lots of conditional panels on my ul.R but they aren't working as before when the submit button is added - the UI is not updated automatically until the button is click (the conditional panel does not appear and disappear as expected before clicking submit),

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  headerPanel("Citizen Sense PM 2.5 Data Visualization Tool"),

  sidebarPanel(

    # Function options.
    radioButtons(
        inputId = "plot", 
        label = "Select a graph or a plot:", 
        choices = c(
            "Line Graph" = "line", 
            "Scatter Plot" = "scatter"
            ), 
        selected = NULL, 
        inline = FALSE
        ),

    # Condition for line graph. 
    conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.plot == 'line'",
        radioButtons(inputId = "lineVariation", 
            label = "Choose a variation:", 
            choices = c(
                "Multiple" = "multiple", 
                "Single" = "single"
                ), 
            selected = NULL, 
            inline = FALSE)
        ),


    submitButton("Submit")

  ),
...
```

Any ideas what I can do about it?

Comment: Can you provide more detail?  In what sense are they not working as before?

Comment: It appears the submit button is intended to make all reactivity wait for hitting the button.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24220105/can-i-have-multiple-submit-buttons-in-r-shiny

Comment: It may make more sense to use RenderUI instead of conditionalPanel.  See here for additional help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948302/shiny-passing-reactivevalues-to-conditionalpanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the issue, do the following:

1. Switch out the submit button and use an action button instead.
2. Write an output using RenderUI to either show nothing if scatter or show the radiobutton if line plot.
3. Modify #2 above so that its reference to input$plot is isolated and only updated when hitting the action button from #1.